# How to replace value of text box?

Tags: forms, input-formats

I have 2 input fields in my drupal form. When end user inserts some value in first input, I want to auto insert the second input field. How can I achieve this.

Here is my code.

input form element 1

```
// total fee of the payment schedule
    $form['fee'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Fee Amount:',
        '#default_value' => (isset($fee_details->fee)) ? $fee_details->fee : '',
        '#maxlength' => 5,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#description' => t('Fee amount'),
        '#id' => "fee",
        '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_integer'),       
'#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'replace_fee_instalment', 
  'wrapper' => 'replace_textfield_div',
),
    );
```

Input field 2nd is

```
 $form['amount'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Instalment'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#default_value' => ($amount) ? $amount : '',
        '#maxlength' => 5,
        '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_integer'),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u need to use javascript for this. 
on the keypress event handler for the first textbox, u can get the text of the first textbox and update the second textbox using javascript itself